# Trouble removing www from url with https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, no-www

I want to remove `www` from URL but,

I am having an issue removing www from url with https (**Apache Server**).

I have added the following code in `.htaccess` file, it works, but when I go to http://www.zubizi.com it doesn't work, what I need to do for that????

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://zubizi.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the following changes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://zubizi.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```